# I have a error RemotingSendRequestException

Tags: require

I have a error when I use Springboot3+graalvm+rocketMq,if I use jar,I can do it ,but when i get Graalvm ,itis error.could you help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nWkW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m35fz.png)

I want get success ,when i do it